# Print image with custom offset

Tags: ios, swift

I want to show `UIPrintInteractionController` to print image with own size and location on the sheet, but I've tried to set `UIViewPrintFormatter` with edge insets and my image is lost from screen

```
let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary:nil)
printInfo.orientation = .portrait
printInfo.jobName = "Tracking"
printInfo.outputType = .photo

let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
printController.delegate = self
printController.showsNumberOfCopies = true
printController.printingItem = self.docImage.image
let formatter = UIViewPrintFormatter()
formatter.perPageContentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 20)
printController.printFormatter = formatter

printController.present(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
```